# How to correctly match a variable against an IPv4 regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to create a simple function checking whether a variable is a valid IPv4 address, or not.

Currently, I'm just trying the code with an [online tool](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html).

I copied the regex from stackexchange and tried to match it against a hardcoded variable, but the online editor claims it's invalid JavaScript code.

```
ip='127.0.0.1';

if (ip.match(^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$){
    alert('IPv4');
}
else{
    alert('no IPv4');
}
```

How do I correctly check if a static variable is a valid IPv4 address with a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to surround the regex with delimiter:

```
if (ip.match(/^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/)){
//    here __^                                                                                                                                                     and here __^
```

You could use a quantifier to reduce the length of regex:

```
if (ip.match(/^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]){3}$/)) {
```

Comment: When using regex literal syntax the dot escaping should just be `\.`. When using string syntax `("regex")` then yeah, the dot escape would be `\\.`

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the regex may need to be delimited, but when I substitute your if statement(s) with mine, I still get an invalid JavaScript code according to the website I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I believe a closing `)` is missing, that's it though - thanks for the answer!